# Can every real number be uniquely represented as a sum of a rational number and an irrational number $\in [0, 1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, real-numbers

I've needed to prove the *transitivity* of the following relation on the set of all real numbers:

> $x − y$ is a rational number.

Immediately I've thought *"Every real number can be uniquely represented as a sum of a rational number (let's call it $q$) and an irrational number $q' \in [0, 1)$"*; from which it follows that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x = q + q'$, $x$ is  rational number iff $q' = 0$.

I am not going into the details of how to prove the transitivity property using this lemma as it is easy enough and unrelated to my question anyway. Instead, what I am asking is, how can I prove my assumption which I've realised might not be *obvious* enough. :)

**Edit:** Or, do you think it's obvious enough, and that I shouldn't worry about it?

Thanks!

Comment: $q' \in [0, 1)$, so it can be equal to 0.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question: $x = q + q' = (q+0.1) + (q'-0.1)$, so you don't have unique representation?  (replace $0.1$ by $0.\dots1$) so that the irrational part becomes positive.

Comment: Why didn't you think "*Sure it's transitive, because the sum of two rational numbers is rational*"?

Comment: $q'$ cannot be $0$ as $0$ is a rational number.

Comment: @Jens: It seems  I misread ‘Can every real number …’ as ‘Can every irrational number …’ . I removed my comment (and will remove this one in a moment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This claim is wrong. Let's take $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then we may subtract two rationals $0\leq{}r≠r'\leq{}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and the result is an irrational. Adding the difference with $r$ respectively $r'$ gives us back our irrational number. So your representation is not unique. Aside from that you can subtract rational numbers from irrational ones.

Answer (score 5):

A rational number can not be represented as a sum of a rational number and an irrational number because the difference of two rational numbers is rational number. Of course, an irrational number can be represented as a sum of a rational number and an irrational number because an irrational number minus a rational number is again an irrational number.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Your answer doesn't address the "uniqueness" in the title.

Comment: I mean this claim is not ture. So, there is no point in discussing  the "uniqueness".  An irrational number can be represented as a sum of a rational number and an irrational number and clearly it is not unique.

Comment: Thank for reply.  I upvote every answer.

Comment: Many thanks.  GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會